# In place edit update text

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to do in-place editing way in my site.
Now I set up all the things I need.
When the user clicks Submit, it will send the `id` of the `div` element (what kind of content) and the new value to update.

Here's my code:

```
if($pedit = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `accounts` SET ? = ? WHERE `id`= ? ")){
   $pedit->bind_param("sss", $id, $value, $_SESSION["user_id"]);
   $pedit->execute();
   $pedit->free_result();
   $pedit->close();
}
```

I don't know why it doesn't update the information.
`$id` = the row that change: description, fullname, email etc.
`$value` = the new information about `$id`. User can update his profile information.

The code doesn't show me any kind of error but still doesn't update.

Comment: It doesn't work because you are not permitted to use `?` placeholders in place of _column or table_ identifiers. They may only be used for scalar values (those values _assigned_ to columns)

Comment: So for your input variable `$id`, you can't use a placeholder. Instead, you have to put that variable into the query (which you were trying to avoid by using `prepare()/bind_param()/execute()`)  but you can first validate it with an array of acceptable possible column names. I'm looking around for an existing question that illustrates it - this is asked often...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't specify a column name as a parameter in a prepared statement. You'll instead have to substitute column names into the statement before preparing it. Don't forget to whitelist editable column names to make sure no unwanted SQL gets executed.

```
<?php
$accounts_editable_cols = array(
    'name'=>true, 'street'=>true, 'city'=>true,
    'region'=>true, 'postal'=>true, 'phone'=>true
);

// prevent SQL injection by whitelisting column names
if (!array_key_exists($id, $accounts_editable_cols)) return false;

$pedit = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `accounts` SET $id = ? WHERE `id`= ? ")
if ($pedit) {
    $pedit->bind_param("ss", $value, $_SESSION["user_id"]);
    $pedit->execute();
    $pedit->free_result();
    $pedit->close();
}
```